# Conditional Statement - Best Way to Remove Nav on Contact Page

Tags: conditional-content, theme-twenty-eleven

I was thinking of removing navigation on my contact page.

I was thinking of inserting a conditional statement and an inline CSS style to "display: none;" if the page template was the contact page.

Is there a better way?

I'm using Twenty Eleven as a parent theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try putting this code in your functions.php

```
function remove_contact_nav( $nav_menu, $args ){

    if( is_page_template('template-contact.php') || is_page( 'contact' ) ) {
        $nav_menu = null;
    }

    return $nav_menu;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'remove_contact_nav', 11, 2 );
```

The if condition need to be modified as per your template name or the second condition would also do if your contact page slug is `contact`